# Android Studio Arctic fox test run shows "nothing here"

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, junit

[image: the issue in hand]

I've tried so many things from invalidate cache/restart to clean re installing android studio multiple times now. nothing seems to work.

in my build.gradle (project level)

```
dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"
...
```

build.gradle (app level)

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.13.2"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0"
}
```

I've enabled corretto-1.8 version of the gradle jdk in settings and the plugins for JUint is enabled.
I cannot seems to find any solution to this issue.

P.S. I have update the windows to windows 11 recently. The above issue was persisting before that.

Comment: Same. the gradle tasks ▶ are also showing 'nothing here'. do you see any IDE errors? I got update failed for ActionGroup here but cannot submit it to google due to poor network.